# jquery .text() undetermined string literal

Tags: jquery, text, addition

I'm playing around with codeigniter and jquery, and I was trying to take some text from mysql and insert it into a `<P>` tag. The method works when I just say "hello world", but when it grabs the text form SQL and inserts it I get a undetermined string literal error. This is my code:

```
$('#register').click(function(){
  <?
    $query = $this->db->get_where('eula', array('id'=>'1'));
    $result = $query->result();
    $eula = (string)$result[0]->eula;
    echo '$(\'#eulaText\').append(\''.$eula.'\'\);';
  ?>
    console.log("$string=".$string);
});
```

I have a lorum ipsum string in sql that I want to insert into the page.

I could use some advice, and I apologize for the sloppy code.

Comment: You are using php-code outside of your php area (`<? ?>`). `console.log("$string=".$string);` -> you have never set `$string` and you have to put that into your php area and have to echo this line.

Comment: @da_re That line won't throw though. `"$string=".$string` will be parsed as property access, like `"foo".bar`, and will return `undefined`. (In JavaScript, property access on string literals returns `undefined`.)

Comment: Yeah, thats why I used a comment instead of an answer :) .

Comment: Aside from the errors in the code, why is the jQuery function coded in php?

Comment: I thought I had to have the file as PHP when using codeigniter. I also realize that the console log was incorrect, but the echo line should work. If I did `echo '$(\'#eulaText\').append(\'Hello\');';'`, it works. Plus I ended up writing it like this, because I would get the error regardless.T

Comment: @user2127823 Try `echo '$(\'#eulaText\').append(\''.$eula.'\');';`

Comment: do yourself a big favor and keep php and javascript totally separate from each other. Depending on workflow, there are many ways to avoid mixing the two.

Comment: @JustAguy If you're referring to the <? ?> inside the function, it isn't.  The PHP is parsed and it echos the the string first and then when the page loads, the javascript is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicions is you have a character, which terminates your javascript string, in the php variable that is returned.  You're passing a single-quoted string (when the page loads and the javascript is evaluated), and if that php variable (eula) contains a single-quote it will terminate the string which is passed to the append() method, causing the rest of the "eula" to be evaluated as JavaScript code.

I've worked around this by following the example I provided in this stackoverflow post:

[jQuery prepend php block of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949888/jquery-prepend-php-block-of-code/15950147#15950147)

It may not be the best solution but it ensures the javascript string literal that is passed to append() will not contain any illegal characters which could terminate it.